# Show full image from time to time - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want from time to time (after the user does 3 steps )  to show an image .

I have a class for Image that contains an Uiimageview and diffrent methods (if i click opens an url etc )

I have the first class that contains an UiWindow and when i acces image i do window addSubview:myimageclass.view....and this is working

but I have more other classes that don t have window  but tableview or mapview....I don t know how to add code in this classes . I shell show the image with add just from time to time ...how can i display it ?

i know android programming and on ios I am new , in android i put the image in separate activity and i was calling this and i set a sting and after i was returning to activity from string .

Thanks a lot , 
Raluca

Answer (score 1):

You could keep your UIImageView as a property of appDelegate. Let's call it
imageView.

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: hide this imageView and add it to appDelegate.window like so:

```
[self.imageView setHidden:YES];
[self.window addSubview:imageView];
```

You can then define two methods of appDelegate:

```
-(void) showImage {
[self.imageView setHidden:NO];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView];

}

-(void) hideImage {
[self.imageView setHidden: YES];
}
```

and use this two methods when needed